# Tagging policy-related questions on Meta

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Making it easier to find policy-related "rulings" here on Meta (e.g. "do we permit X in a question/answer"), I've just created the `policy` tag. While walking through our questions to apply the tag to those relevant, I stumpled upon the `scope` tag – which seems to be exactly for that, with one exception: according to its wiki excerpt, it's intended for questions (only).

So, before I uselessly tag all kind of questions:

- shall we use the `scope` tag for answers as well?
- as my example shows "scope" is not always the intuitive thing one looks for, shall we make `policy` a synonym to it?
- until decided, is it a good idea to still already walk the questions, tagging them either `scope` or `policy` – and in case we decide they are the same, a merge can take care for that? Background for this: Many scope/policy related questions carry neither tag, and thus are not as easy to find.

Comment: I wonder if [meta-tag:faq] could work for this

Comment: @Undo might be an idea. Just afraid it would overload that, as FAQ is a bit wider from the scope (and AFAIK only mods can use that tag?). As I got no response yet, I've decided to go over our questions and apply either the `scope` or `policy` tag where it applies, and set up a tag-wiki for `policy` (also pointing to `scope`). Not too many questions involved currently, so we still can decide what to do about it and act easily. Both tags are closely related, but IMHO not totally overlapping.

Comment: It's a mod-only tag, but I'd be inclined to apply it if someone raised a custom flag on the question. I also agree that it's not a perfect fit, though.

Comment: Thanks, @Undo. Shall we wait for some more opinions first? No need to hurry that up, better have some consense before "overloading" the faq tag. I hope some more of our active users will announce their opinions here (yeah, I'm an optimist ;)

Comment: Oh absolutely, it'd be nice to have other folks' opinions here.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Use as synonyms**  You are definitely right that scope is *not always the intuitive thing*.
2. Use the scope tag **for answers as well**. I think someone put 'question' in the wiki excerpt he/she assumed scope/policy issues would always be for questions (i.e. not realizing that there could be scope/policy issues with answers as well).

One caveat: Just looking at it 'from language': policy *includes* scope.